# Is there a way of doing this?

Tags: python

The problem is this:

```
groups=[1,2,3..etc] # all the way up to 16 numbers (random numbers)

for i in groups:
    if groups.index(i)% 2 != 0:
        value=groups[groups.index(i)]-groups[groups.index(i)-1]
        print(value)
```

Using that code, I should get 8 numbers, but the number fluctuates. Can anyone help me find a solution or tell me what's wrong?

Comment: is it possible to have duplicate numbers in `groups`?  `print([1,1].index(1))` will always return zero.

Comment: What is the code supposed to *do*? Print `(groups[1] - groups[0])`, `(groups[3] - groups[2])`, etc? `for x in range(0, len(groups), 2): print(groups[x] - groups[x-1])`.

Comment: there is, thank you, I didn't see that!! Is there a way of doing this without index??

Comment: (There are also ways to use `zip`, but iterating over a range of indices is simpler for a comment.)

Comment: a bunch of ways.  @chepner has provided an example.  Consider checking out `enumerate` for future reference.

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify what your code is suppose to do ? Provide example input values and what the output should be. I think your main problem comes from missunderstanding what .index() does but I'm not sure since it's not clear what you try to achieve

Comment: Please modify you question title in order to give information about the question is being made.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have random sequence of numbers, sometimes it contains duplicates,   and `groups.index(i)` returns the index of first occurrence. More pythonic way is:

```
for i, n in enumerate(groups):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        print(n)
```

`enumerate` is a good way to generate `(position , value)` tuples from the list